# Running android emulator using "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

**EDIT :** This issue has been resolved, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048046/5522344 . It needs Windows 10 1903 or above.

I am trying to run Android Emulator on Windows 10 1803, as per the post [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html).

The requirements are

1. AMD Ryzen processors - mine is Ryzen 1600
2. Virtualization enabled - yes checked that
3. Hyper-V turned off - yes
4. The emulator version is 29.2.3 or later

I can run the emulator using the Hyper-V enabled.

But I am unable to run the emulator after going through the mentioned steps.

---

- This is the Android Studio version

[image: My Android Studio version]

- Current Settings as per the post
  [image: settings]
- Emulator Version
  [image: emulator]
- Success message after installing the driver
  [image: result]
- Emulator fails to run
  [image: issue]

Can anyone point out what I missed here?

Comment: Not sure, did you make sure windows sandbox is unchecked? Also why are you getting two service name: gvm when you run that bat?

Comment: This issue has been solved. I cannot delete this post. The only issue was version conflict which is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO It is not the right android version:

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors#download-and-install

> Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors is released
>   through android-studio.  However, only Android Studio with version 4.0
>   canary 5 or above can both download and install/update the driver. 
>   Otherwise, the Android Studio will only download the driver package
>   without performing installation. In the latter case, users are
>   required to install the driver manually.

Looks like android-studio 3.2.1 will only download the driver.

The link to download preview versions is:

> https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

I tried with 4.1 CANARY 5 and it works

Comment: This issue has been solved. I cannot delete this post. The only issue was version conflict which is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is filing a bug to google. This is not a suitable question to address at Stackoverflow. - from Author of the Software.

Comment: I did file a bug and the problem is now solved. Thanks.